# use getters in ViewModel instead of subscribing to Model

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, model, viewmodel

That week I learn that we can use getters/setters in javascript.
So I tried to use it in my current code.

For now my ViewModel register to the Model in order to get notified when Model has changed.

Using getters I can get RID of that and simply returns the value of the field in model to the viewModel.

ex:

```
Model = {
field: aValue
}

ViewModel = {}
 Object.defineProperty(ViewModel , aField{
      get: function () {
        return Model.field;
             });
         }
    });
```

Am I right? is it ok?

Comment: This is an interesting thought. When a page loads, all of the javascript needed for the page is loaded and publicly viewable. Where your theory in this example would become confusing and difficult, would be when the javascript gets more complex. it would still work, but it may be more difficult to modify in the future. Overall when you keep things separate it stays less confusing. If we were talking about a compiled language on the other hand, this would not be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SynchroDynamic makes a good point about code readability and also the creeping complexity that may arise as your system develops.

Presumably you are using a framework of some sort that provides a mechanism for data-binding. Data-binding is usually an automatic process based on change events. For 2-way binding both the **source** and **target** of the bound pair must trigger events if data changes and the **source** and **target** must also respond to those events (by registering for them) so that data remains synchronised.

`Am I right?`

Yes you are right that you can (in the sense that its possible) use get/set etc and disable the frameworks data-binding mechanisms.

`is it ok?`

Probably not, in all but the most trivial cases.

1) If you a using a framework that supports data-binding, other readers of your code will be confused as to why you took that approach, when a perfectly good (and documented) mechanism is available.

2) As SynchroDynamic points out, things will quickly get out of hand when the number of views and viewModels increase and you will have to manually keep track of the get/sets.

3) Unit testing might also become a lot more complicated!